# Is this a good way to redirect mobile devices to the mobile version of your webpage?

Tags: javascript, mobile

In order to retirect users of my website to a mobile version of the site, I was thinking of using the following script (which would run onload of the website):

```
function devdetect() {
var x = screen.width;

if (x < 500) {
    window.location = "http://m.1encrypt.com"
}


}
```

Is this an effective way of performing this task, or would it fail to work properly for some devices? I know that there are numerous threads on here relating to detecting mobile devices. My question is, what's wrong with this method?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery?rq=1  for detection

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-page-redirect-using-jquery/506004#506004 for redirects

Comment: Thanks, that looks good. However, I was interested in why this method is not as good as others?

Comment: Screen width can be > 500 on mobile devices too. Think landscape mode and tablets.

Comment: On my iPhone 6s, the screen.width function always returns 375px, regardless of the orientation of the screen.

Comment: Check out emulation for different devices in the chrome console. F12 --> Three dots in the bottom console pane, top left corner.